# Are there any commercial add on programming controls for Mac  and iOS Cocoa/Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa, custom-controls

If developing for the Windows .NET APIs I can augment my efforts with 100's of commerically available add-on controls, graphing APIs and other usefull stuff. Can anyone point me in the direction of similar commerical software for Mac Cocoa/Objective C development?

**Additionally:**

Are there enough developers to do this commercially?

The point of my question was really is the Mac developer market mature enough to support commercial developer add-ons. I know there is "Open Source"... which everything seems to default to... mainly because no one has a led the way yet. Problem with open source freeware is one day were all turn into poor thin semi unskilled homeless people who plug free things together. We deserve better!

In case you hadn't noticed in the Mac market people are willing to pay for good stuff.

I have a history of selling development tools. You don't have to just give this stuff away.

Tony

Comment: Are there specific kinds of frameworks or controls you're looking for? You might have better luck getting an answer - whether Open Source or commercial - if you're more specific. Mac developers probably won't know what's common in the .NET or Windows world.

Comment: Also, is there a specific reason you're asking for commercial frameworks?  Open Source frameworks are very common in Mac development and have been for a very long time.

Comment: Things like Sparkle and PSMTabBarControl (some of the popular open source things you disdain) were most certainly not written by semi-unskilled homeless people. In those cases, contributors to them now work for Apple on UIKit and Foundation...

Comment: ;-) I have nothing against Open Source. As my question says I'm interested whether it is viable for a company to survive selling software libraries for iOS/Mac development.

Answer (score 6):

Most such reusable source code and frameworks that I've seen are free, not commercial. Of those, most are under a BSD or MIT license, which means that you can use them in <del>commercial</del> closed-source software. (A very few come under one of the GPLs, which prohibit this.)

I have [a list of these](http://boredzo.org/opensourcelinks), although it is vastly incomplete now. I have a longer list in OmniOutliner, along with a grand plan for a better website for presenting it.

There's also [MacCode](http://code.google.com/p/maccode/), which is a repository of reusable source code and frameworks.

Comment: GPL and LGPL don't "prohibit" use in commercial software. They impose requirements on licensees that are sometimes contrary to the goals of commercial software developers.

Comment: The LGPL doesn't prohibit use in closed-source software, either. It mandates that the source _of the LGPL component_ be made available, and that substituting that component for an alternative be permitted. The rest of your source can be unpublished.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen Cocoa reusable source code and frameworks under the LGPL. I was specifically referring to the GPLs.

Comment: http://www.collaboration-world.com/cgi-bin/project/description.cgi?pid=3 Pantomime.framework is LGPL.

Answer (score 4):

The [Omni Frameworks](http://www.omnigroup.com/developer/) are used in commercial software, though they themselves are open-source. I doubt there are enough OS X developers to really sustain a small independent closed-source library vendor. You may be able to publish open-source libraries and sell consulting or documentation services.

Answer (score 1):

I found a great site with both Mac and iOS custom controls and source code on it. Check out [Cocoa Controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com)